My BeanPostProcessor isn't called anymore for all my beans
I have a rather old Spring application, XML based config.
I have a BeanPostProcessor that is configured at the top of the config file as a <bean>. Worked fine, all the other beans in that file had the postProcessAfterInitialization() method called as expected.
This config file is then imported into the main context config file. I've had to add a new JPA (hibernate) unit & config, and a new bean. Now, only some of the beans in this other config file that's imported gets created after my BeanPostProcessor is created and registered. Most are created after my BeanPostProcessor. I've tried to add depends-on="MyBeanPostProcessor" to the <bean> definitions, but that hasn't helped.
I know MyBeanPostProcessor hasn't been created or registered yet because I have a breakpoint in AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization() and the getBeanPostProcessors() that it calls to iterate over all of the BeanPostProcessors doesn't include MyBeanPostProcessor for the first few of my beans, but then suddenly it is there.
I'd have though the depends-on would solve that, force Spring to wait until MyBeanPostProcessor was created and registered.

Too little information. Which beans are skipped (not all beans are created equal and some are created very early in the process). Add the configuration etc.

@M.Deinum so I have a whole bunch of beans that inherit from the same Interface. They're all identical <bean>s, other than different name & class implementation. They all are in the same config file after the configuration for MyBeanPostProcessor. Further, as I said, I added a depends-on="MyBeanPostProcessor" to all of their configurations.

Again too little information. Don't describe but show. You might think something is like that but in reality it doesn't have to be. So add your configuration, beans etc. etc.
